# macOS Sierra Volume Menu control strange behavior

Tags: mac, macos, sound-volume

Anybody else have this issue after upgrading to Sierra?

Clicking the volume button and it shifts all the icons in the Mac menu... Never used to do that on El Capitan. The result is the mouse cursor doesn't line up with the control below it. I know they switched it to a horizontal control but I don't think it's supposed to shift all the icons right??

[image: macOS Volume menu - http://www.giphy.com/gifs/3o6ZsUxIHlnv8KjT2w]

Is this fixable or Sierra bug?

Update: New gif.

Comment: Can you please make a gif showing the entire menu bar up to the top right corner of the screen? It seems as if some other menu item is making this happen. I want to actually see where the shifting stops.

Comment: @IronCraftMan ok new gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had this problem, and found a solution.It was happening because of the hidden mirroring option. just go to System Preferences> Display>untick 'show mirroring options' and the problem will get solved.